# Keyboard key typing repeatedly when pressing any key only once

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, motherboard

My Zebronics USB keyboard (zeb k11) is typing keys repeatedly even if i press any key only once. I am using this keyboard with Intel DG41TY Desktop motherboard running Windows 7. This iss an exaaamplle of ssenntence wwith this tyyping probllem. This is very difficult to type this question, need to press backspace several times to correct letters. Sometimes letters may repeat 2 times or 3 or more times. **When I use the same keyboard with my acer emachines netbook, there is no problem.**

The problem is not specific for Windows 7, same problem when I use Ubuntu or entering BIOS settings. I changed the keyboard settings key repeat-rate and repeat-delay on Windows 7, but this has not fixed the issue. This problem is common for all the keys, including shift, alt, ctrl,, spacce, etc. For example, if I need to type capital A (shift+A), when I press shift and then A, in this short time, shift will be applied several times, and in Windows 7 "Do you want to turn on Sticky Keys?" dialog will be shown.

[image]

Same effect like when we pressing and release shift key 5 times. What may be the problem?

Comment: It would appear to be a hardware issue of some sort since it is independent of OS and you already tried it on another system. Is your computer older or newer? Is something using up all of the I/O bandwidth? Try unplugging all of your peripherals and only have the keyboard plugged in. Does that still have the same issue? Also have you tried another keyboard on the same machine?

Comment: PC bought in 2008, it has PS/2 port also. Previously I was using it with a PS/2 keyboard without any issues. I just  disconnected all other peripherals. But still have  the issue

Comment: So a few ideas - Can you use a usb to ps2 converter to see if that solves it? 2008 is a bit on the older side so it could be possible that something is hogging the memory and it is simply lag you are experiencing? How much memory is available / in use?

Comment: total 3 GB of RAM. Normally use 30%-50% of total memory in Windows 7. Is this problem has any relation with memory ? Regarding usb to ps2 converter, yes, it's an iidea..! ok I will try this method, i don't have this device, i'll buy one and check and let you know if it is successful.

Comment: My idea could be wrong but I believe the ps2 controller and usb controller are on different channels so it would be interesting to swap which channel it is being used on. IF this proves to be a success then something is bogging down your usb controller.

Comment: At last I found the reason.. :). The reason was very strange. I was working with it by connecting PC cabinet and the monitor in the same power supply. Those power plugs where very close to each other. As fortune I just checked with connecting my computer in another power supplies in my hall. Connected the monitor and cabinet to different plugs, and keyboard is working like a charm without any issues of repeating the keys. I don't know what was the issue, may be some thing electric signal variation issues. Try this, if any of you have the same issue.

Comment: Put it as an answer and layout exactly what you did then you can accept your own answer for anyone in the future to reference

Answer (score 0):

> At last I found the reason.. :). The reason was very strange. I was working with it by connecting PC cabinet and the monitor in the same power supply. Those power plugs where very close to each other. As fortune I just checked with connecting my computer in another power supplies in my hall. Connected the monitor and cabinet to different plugs, and keyboard is working like a charm without any issues of repeating the keys. I don't know what was the issue, may be some thing electric signal variation issues. Try this, if any of you have the same issue.

It seems to be working. In my case I'm using the Keyboard (k11) with my laptop. No matter connected to another Laptop/PC suddenly it would behave like the exact way by repeating letters, even rebooting the laptop doesn't help. BIOS, Ubuntu tried everything but the result is same.

I used to shutdown the laptop for around 30 mins with keyboard unplugged, I would connect the keyboard and turn on the laptop it would work fine(sometimes).

> As fortune I just checked with connecting my computer in another power supplies in my hall. Connected the monitor and cabinet to different plugs, and keyboard is working like a charm without any issues of repeating the keys.

But just before I found this thread, the keyboard was working fine and laptop was charging. I turned off the charger from the power strip and surprisingly the keyboard starts to behave weirdly. Also from  your experience I'm convinced it's about the power supply issue.

**So what I did is unplugged the keyboard from the laptop, switched on the charger from the power strip and connected the keyboard back to the laptop.. The keyboard works great.** It's surely something related to the power supply. Never faced this type of weird problem.